# How to re-render functional component on parent state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component

I'd like to re-render the functional child component when the parent state changed.
When I use the class component as a child then I know how to solve it.
In this case, I can use `componentWillReceiveProps`.

But my child component is the functional component.

I have the table component and there is some radio button in my page.
When I choose the special radio button the table content is changed. This is working well.
If I set 4th page of the table and I choose the other radio button then the table content length is changed. (At this time I'd like to see the first page of the table)
So when choosing the special radio button I set the page as 0.(In parent component)
But at this time child component doesn't re-render.
How can I do it?

This is my code.

parent side

```
export default class Report extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        table_data:[],
        page: 0,
        analys_type: "1"
    }
  }
  setData = () => {
    ......
    ......
  }

  handleChangeAnalysType = (event) => {
      this.setState({
          analys_type: event.target.value,
          page: 0
      }, () => {
          this.setData();
      });
  }
  render() {
       <div>
           <Paper className="input-box">
                <div>
                     <FormControl component="fieldset">
                          <RadioGroup name="analys_type" value={this.state.analys_type} onChange={this.handleChangeAnalysType}>
                               <FormControlLabel value="1" control={<Radio />} label="Day" />
                               <FormControlLabel value="2" control={<Radio />} label="Week" />
                               <FormControlLabel value="3" control={<Radio />} label="Month" />
                          </RadioGroup>
                      </FormControl>
                  </div>
             </Paper>
             <Paper className="table-box">
                  <AnalysTable table_data={this.state.table_data} analys_type={this.state.analys_type} current_page={this.state.page} />
             </Paper>
       </div>
  }
}
```

child component

```
export default function AnalysTable(props) { 
     const [page, setPage] = React.useState(props.current_page);
     const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10);
     const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
         setPage(newPage);
     };

     const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
           setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
          setPage(0);
     };

     render (
         <div>
              <TableContainer>
               ......
              </TableContainer>
              <TablePagination
                    rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
                    component="div"
                    count={props.table_data.length}
                    page={page}
                    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                    labelRowsPerPage="rows"
               />
         </div>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change you component state on parent change so:

```
//here you initialize the page state 
const [page, setPage] = React.useState(props.current_page);

//add and effect on current_page change
useEffect(()=>setPage(props.current_page), [props.current_page])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried but not working. `useEffect(()=>console.log(props.current_page), [props.current_page])` I put this line but there is no character in my console panel when I choose the radio button.

Comment: that's wired....did you log anything inside the child componente after the parent render?

Comment: Ah.. I noticed why dosn't woking `useEffect`. I use this `useEffect(()=>setPage(props.current_page), [props])` and This is working well. Anyway, thank you so much.Please update your answer.